# Ubuntu 15.10 Long boot time issue

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu 15.10 on my desktop running on core i7 4930k, nvidia 780ti, 16gb ram, 120gb ssd.

Every time I try to boot to ubuntu, it takes around 4-5 minutes. I used dmesg to check log. It looks something like this:

[image]

This thing keeps happening for 5 minutes and then the login screen appears. I tried disconnecting/reconnecting all my usb devices (mouse, keyboard and headset) during this loading period and still it doesn't stop. Please help.

PS: I am very new to ubuntu.

UPDATE: I entered this on the terminal:

```
lspci |grep -i ehci
```

And nothing new shows up:

[image]

Entered this on the terminal:

```
lspci -v | grep -i hci
```

And got this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci |grep -i ehci` in your post?

Comment: @TungTran Thank you for your reply. I updated my post.

Comment: try `lspci -v | grep -i hci`

Comment: @TungTran Updated my post.

Comment: You can just paste text from the terminal in a <pre> tag, not screenshots. Also, output of `lsusb -t` could be useful.

Comment: I can suggest to remove or disable `ehci_hcd` driver but it means your USB 3.0 may function only at USB 1.1 speeds.

Answer (score 0):

`xhci_hcd` is the usb-3 driver for the chip that the usb devices plug into. The driver is interacting poorly either with the chip or one of the devices. Hopefully, one of the devices.

Try removing all usb devices, then booting. Don't plug them in until you get to the login screen. This will tell you if the problem is in the chip or the devices. If the chip, you could try:

1. Upgrading to a newer kernel. Maybe a mainline kernel. Possibly whatever's wrong has been fixed. Mainline kernels are here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
2. Disable xHCI, if you can find a switch for that in your BIOS.
3. Ask somebody who knows more.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As you said, I tried booting up after removing all usb devices but the same issue persists. I will try the other steps that you mentioned and let you know. Thanks, again.